# How to run C++ application in Android SHELL

Tags: android, shell, android-ndk, g++

I want to run `hello world` written on C++ and compiled with `Android toolchain 9`, but I faced with issue: by default I have no permissions to launch it and I can't change permissions using chmod`.

I used `Android 2.3.3 - Api Level 10`

Application was compiled by cross compiler for `API level 9`

Procedure:

Compile application:

> ~/toolchain_andr9/bin/  arm-linux-androideabi-g++ helloworld.cpp

Then send application to SDCARD on the emulator:

```
>adb push a.out /mnt/sdcard
```

then go to SHELL and try to run `a.out`:

```
>adb shell
> 
>/mnt/sdcard/a.out
```

And result is:

```
>`/mnt/sdcard/a.out: permission denied`
```

command `ls -l` shows rights for `a.out`:

```
>`----rwxr-x system   sdcard_rw   863656 2012-04-12 22:42 a.out`
```

I tried to change permissions:

```
>chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard/a.out
```

But rights don't change:

```
>`----rwxr-x system   sdcard_rw   863656 2012-04-12 22:42 a.out`
```

I think I have left some important thing using android.

Could anybody help me and give me a way how to run application in `Android SHELL?

Thanks a lot.

P.S. sorry for my English =)

Comment: Do you have a root? Без рута может не выйти фокус: http://gimite.net/en/index.php?Run%20native%20executable%20in%20Android%20App

Comment: try placing your file under /data/local there you should be able to chmod your file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, the SD card is mounted with option `noexec`, that disallows the execution of any file on the card, no matter what it's permissions(even `-rwxrwxrwx`), so you need to move the file to another location and then execute it.

The easiest is to move the file to `/data/local/tmp/` and execute it using the full path (usual POSIX PATH semantics).

```
> adb push a.out /data/local/tmp/a.out
> adb shell
> chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/a.out
> /data/local/tmp/a.out
```

This **does not** require *root access* and **survives** *reboot*.

Answer (score 4):

If you have rooted your phone you can do a `mount -o remount,rw /mnt/sdcard` and it should run.

I've tried it on my Android.

Comment: Does this work? Has anyone else tried this? Doesbit remove the noexec flag? Does the sdcard remount on reboot? I've messed with the format (vfat > ext2) and it made android very mad. Had to use `newfs_msdos` to fix it, so I'm hesitant to mess with sdcard.

Comment: @MarkMikofski This doesn't survive reboot, and the `sdcard` mounts normally on a reboot.

Comment: awesome, that totally works, it just removes `nosuid, nodev, noexec` flags!