# C/C++ unit test on Android ARM emulator - Ubuntu

Tags: android, c++, c, eclipse, ubuntu

I have a C/C++ project in Ubuntu. I want to run the unit test and code coverage for this C++ project for Android_ARM platform. How can I do that? I have been looking for an emulator which can do that, but I have not had much success. I am working on Ubuntu 14.04, and planning to use eclipse IDE for my development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise using Android Studio, as Eclipse is no longer supported by Google for Android development. You can start up an emulator from Android Studio, then communicate with it via adb to run unit tests. See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133274/how-to-run-c-application-in-android-shell) to get an idea of how to communicate with the emulator via adb. I'll paraphrase the solution below:

```
$ adb push <your-executable> /data/local/tmp/<your-executable> # push the file to the device
$ adb shell # shell into the device
$ chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/<your-executable> # change permissions to allow executing the file
$ /data/local/tmp/<your-executable> # run the executable
```